# Executing a bash loop script from a file

Tags: bash, unix, while-loop, grep, echo

I am trying to execute this in unix. So let's for example say I have five files named after dates, and in each of those files there are thousand of numerical values (six to ten digit number). Now, lets say I also have bunch of numerical values and I want to know which value belongs to which file.I am trying to do it the hard way like below but how do I put all my values in a file and just do a loop from there.

FILES:

```
20170101
20170102
20170103
20170104
20170105
```

Code:

```
for i in 5555555 67554363 564324323 23454657 666577878 345576867; do 
    echo $i; grep -l $i 201701*; 
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, why loop at all? If you have a file containing all your numbers (say `numbers.txt` you can find in which date file each are contained and on what line with a simple

```
grep -nH -w -f numbers.txt 201701*
```

Where the `-f` option simply tells `grep` to use the values contained in the file `numbers.txt` to search in each of the files matching `201701*`. The `-nH` options for listing the line number and filename associated with each match, respectively. And as Ed points out below, the `-w` option to insure `grep` only select lines containing the whole word sought.

Comment: Good to have you here Ed. Yes, word match would be quite helpful. Will amend.

Comment: This doesn't group the results by the words, you'll need another pass over the results to organize them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with a `while` loop and read from the file if you create it as @Barmar suggested:

```
while read -r i; do
    ...
done < numbers.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the values in a file `numbers.txt` and do:

```
for i in $(cat numbers.txt); do
    ...
done
```

Comment: Thanks @Barman, this works perfectly! And it was quite simple actually, maybe if I just followed the logic I would of realized how to pull the values from the file. But I have another question, how can I break the lines. The file containing the values appears below the value it found, but I want it to be next to it. Should I do do echo "$line" or maybe printf "%s\n" "$line"?

Comment: Well actually i do not know if I want a print, maybe I need the output result to be in a new file which I can do with.....  do echo $i >> output.txt; grep -l $i 201701* >> output.txt; done..... but I need the line break to be in the output.txt and only for the values which are in the date files. Sounds so complicated in my head.

Comment: You can do `echo $i $(grep -l $i 201701*)`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, but the output is giving me duplicate results like below. Have I done something to change the bash.

Comment: for i in $(cat home/example.txt); do echo $i; echo $i $(grep -l $i 201701*); done
Result
6456564
6456564 20170125
9383766
9383766
8386353
8386353 20170111

Comment: Well the result output is not exactly like that the lines name of the dates break but it gives me the value that is in the date file twice as well as the value that is not in the date file

Comment: Get rid of the first `echo $i`, since you're echoing it on the next line.

Comment: Did you read my code and understand what it's doing, or just paste it in without thinking?

Comment: No I thought I needed the first echo, that it was the condition. Now I see that I am echoing twice for the same value but only for the second echo I get the result that I actually need. Thanks again Barmar!